# protobuf-net - Serializing objects as properties of [ProtoContract] instances in array

Tags: protobuf-net

There is a type like this:

```
[ProtoContract(UseProtoMembersOnly=true)]
public class ProtoObjectDTO
{
    [ProtoMember(1, DynamicType=true)]
    public object Value { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

There is an array of these objects with more than one instances 
(**parameters** in the following snippet) sent to the service:

```
await client.PostAsync<ProtoObjectDTO[]>(
    route, parameters, new ProtoBufFormatter())
        .ContinueWith((r) =>
        {
            r.Result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            retVal = true;
        });
```

**parameters** contains two instances with **Value** property 
set to valid `[ProtoContract]` objects of **different** types.

When data comes on the server side, it is de-serialized like this:

```
var sentParams = ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize<ProtoObjectDTO[]>(stream);
```

When **sentParams** are examined and compared to **parameters**, 
**Value** within second instance is just a default instance 
of object type in the first instance. This is weird. 
Can you help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added the following test, which works successfully. To investigate, more information about the types involved seems necessary (or ideally, a failing test):

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo
{
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public int A { get; set; }
}
[ProtoContract]
public class Bar
{
    [ProtoMember(4)]
    public string B { get; set; }
}

public void Execute()
{
    var model = TypeModel.Create();
    model.AutoCompile = false;

    Execute(model, "Runtime");
    model.CompileInPlace();
    Execute(model, "CompileInPlace");
    Execute(model.Compile(), "Compile");
    model.Compile("SO17040488", "SO17040488.dll");
    PEVerify.AssertValid("SO17040488.dll");

}

private void Execute(TypeModel model, string caption)
{
    var args = new[] {
        new ProtoObjectDTO { Order = 1, Value = new Foo { A = 123 }},
        new ProtoObjectDTO { Order = 2, Value = new Bar { B = "abc" }},
    };
    var clone = (ProtoObjectDTO[])model.DeepClone(args);
    Assert.AreEqual(2, clone.Length, caption + ":length");
    Assert.AreEqual(1, clone[0].Order, caption + ":order");
    Assert.AreEqual(2, clone[1].Order, caption + ":order");
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(Foo), clone[0].Value, caption + ":type");
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(Bar), clone[1].Value, caption + ":type");
    Assert.AreEqual(123, ((Foo)clone[0].Value).A, caption + ":value");
    Assert.AreEqual("abc", ((Bar)clone[1].Value).B, caption + ":value");
}
```

Comment: Hello Marc, I just had this bug fixed. Thank you (and sorry) for your time. I am making a generic solution for enabling non-REST method signatures in ApiController-s with proto-buf serialization usage. DynamicType=true works like charm in this case :)